# Assembly invalid combination of opcode and operands error

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

```
section .data
    msg db     "hi"

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    lea rbx, msg
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, [rbx]
    mov     rdx, 2
    syscall

    mov    rax, 60
    mov    rdi, 0
    syscall
```

this 64 bit linux assembly code.. help me..

(nasm)

Comment: If you want help, list the command line you're using the nasm's output. Also, put a remark on the line that nasm points to.

Comment: Likely you meant `lea rbx, [rel msg]`

Comment: environmentset@linux-ubuntu:~/Assembly$ nasm -f elf64 asmP.asm ; ld asmP.o ; ./a.out
asmP.asm:7: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Comment: and nasm point  lea rbx, msg

Comment: oh, i will try it